# Prooblema de acentos en SQL y HTML

Tags: html, sql

Estoy intentando mostrar informacion de la bdd, no entiendo porque las palabras con acento me generan caracteres `caciÃ³n` por lo cual no me funciona.

En mi base de datos tengo el siguiente campo:

```
*_PUB_DistribuciÃ³n_Cambio_de_marcaciÃ³n*
```

Supongo que SQL automanticamente al encontrar letra con acento le asigna caracteres.

Mi problema entonces es que cuanto intento mostrarlo me sigue saliendo igual:

```
*_PUB_DistribuciÃ³n_Cambio_de_marcaciÃ³n*
```

en lugar de

```
*_PUB_Distribución_Cambio_de_marcación*
```

Que tengo que hacer para que muestre con acentos en la vista?

Comment: el meta de charset que tienes es de UTF-8? (<meta charset="UTF-8">)

Comment: Si, ya tengo configurado todo utf-8, a menos que me haya brincado una parte en Laravel para esta configuracion

Comment: revisa la pregunta/respuesta que aparece en el primer comentario por favor